# MDI in SWT on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, gtk, swt, mdi

I'd like to create an MDI application using SWT.

I've done extensive searches and reach that the `Decorations` Object is the one responsable for *trying* supporting behavior. However, I've a Linux box, and [the example provided](http://java-gui.info/Apress-The.Definitive.Guide.to.SWT.and.JFace/8886final/LiB0070.html#ch08fig02)
doesn't work for me.

The output of the example provided by the above link is:

[Image](http://java-gui.info/Apress-The.Definitive.Guide.to.SWT.and.JFace/8886final/images/fig240_01_0.jpg)

However, on Linux (GTK), I see only labels without control bars or boxes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the Eclipse Rich Client Platform. It's built on SWT and gives you the full flexibility of the Eclipse User Interface (with views and editors) - and lots of other interesting stuff like a smart plug-in and modularization system or a full-fledged online help. Take a look at the RCP Mail Demo - it's a simple demo program that shows you how to create different views and move them around. (I'd offer my tutorial, but it's written in german. You'll find lots of good stuff around the net.) If you're still interested, there's a book named Eclipse Rich Client Platform available by Jeff McAffer - excellent guide.

Comment: Actually, It is a very small program with 5 or so forms.
I just wanted to give the user the spirit of native windows app. but it seams I'll give him freak Java app spirit using tabbed pans !! :D

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Novocode Application Framework](https://web.archive.org/web/20180421212429/http://www.novocode.com:80/swt/). It has a Desktop Form for exactly that, and I like it, even if tabs are all the hype now. I already used it with great success!

[image: Example for Desktop Form]
<sub>(source: [novocode.com](http://www.novocode.com/swt/ishell-255x156.png))</sub>